# react native application for odoo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mobile, odoo

I want to make mobile app for Vacation requests in Odoo ERP system. I used react native to make the app.  the problem is I tried to take input from  user then pass it to Odoo API to submit it in the system but I cannot find a good method to do it

Odoo api - xmlrpc :

```
var Odoo = require('odoo-xmlrpc');

var odoo = new Odoo({
    url: 'http://abdelazizs-macbook-pro.local',
    port: '8069',
    db: 'hr_2-9_test_11',
    username: 'admin',
    password: 'admin'
});

odoo.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) { return console.log(err); }
    console.log('Connected to Odoo server.');    
});

odoo.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) { return console.log(err); }
    console.log('Connected to Odoo server.');
    var inParams = [];
    inParams.push({'name': 'egg'
    ,'holiday_status_id':parseInt(1)
    , 'date_from':'2018-08-14 16:35:38'
    , 'date_to':'2018-08-16 16:35:38'
    , 'employee_id':parseInt(1)})
    var params = [];
    params.push(inParams);
    odoo.execute_kw('hr.holidays', 'create', params, function (err, value) {
        if (err) { return console.log(err); }
        console.log('Result: ', value);
    });
});
```

we want to replace these default parameters by the user input

```
{'name': 'egg'
    ,'holiday_status_id':parseInt(1)
    , 'date_from':'2018-08-14 16:35:38'
    , 'date_to':'2018-08-16 16:35:38'
    , 'employee_id':parseInt(1)}
```

here is one of the app components which picking date  :

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import DatePicker from 'react-native-datepicker';
import {Text, View} from 'react-native';

export default class Component1 extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {date:"2019-05-15"}



      }

 render(){
    return(

      <View>
        <Text style={{fontSize:25,}}>From</Text>
       <DatePicker
         style={{width: 300,justifyContent: 'center',
         }}
     date={this.state.date}
     mode="date"
     placeholder="select date"
     format="YYYY-MM-DD"

     confirmBtnText="Confirm"
     cancelBtnText="Cancel"

     customStyles={{
       dateIcon: {
         position: 'absolute',
         right: 0,
         top: 4,
         marginRight: 10


       },
       dateInput: {
         marginLeft: 36
       }
       // ... You can check the source to find the other keys.
     }}
     onDateChange={(date) => {this.setState({date: date})}}
   />

  </View>





    );


 }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make a call on your component like

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component{
    state = {
        date: ''
    }
    callToOdoo = () => {
        //your odoo call
    }
    dateHandler = (date) => {
        this.setState({date: date}, () => {
            this.callToOdoo();
        })
    }
    render(){
        return(<View>
              <DatePicker
                  {...}
               onDateChange={{this.dateHandler}}
        />
```